# How can I write a Jenkins email-ext template to display test results like the standard test report

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jelly, email-ext

I have tweaked the standard jelly template to display the current test results in a table, however I really want to be able to display diffs as seen in Jenkins own test results page.

For example:

```
JUnit Tests: 0 failures (±0) , 1 skipped (+1)

Package               Duration   Fail  (diff)  Skip  (diff)  Total  (diff)
foo.bar.baz              89 ms      0      0     1       +1     5       +2
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Write a Groovy template for Email Ext plugin instead of Jelly template. In Groovy template you'll have access to [Build](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Build.html) object for your build. You can then call [getTestResultAction](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html#getTestResultAction%28%29) on it to obtain the [AbstractTestResultAction](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/tasks/test/AbstractTestResultAction.html) for the build which you can then query for everything you need.

Here is a link to [Jenkins Main Module API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org). A sample Groovy template for Ext Email plugin could be found in `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins/email-ext/WEB-INF/classes/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/groovy-html.template`. More info on Groovy template/script usage can be found in [Email Ext plugin documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin).

Comment: @Jon, was this answer helpful?

Comment: I've managed to pull out the failed tests using build.testResultAction.failedTests, but I am not sure how to access all tests

Comment: Looks like accessing the PackageResult's depends on on the type returned by getTestResultAction - AggregatedTestResultAction & TestResultAction require different handling.

Comment: Here's a [link to the groovy-html.template](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/groovy-html.template).

Comment: This is now "easier" with Jenkins pipelines, you can write the email template in a `@NonCPS` annotated method in the Jenkinsfile and access the test results with `def testResult = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction.class)`

Answer (score 5):

If you are struggle on how to access it via internal API (difficult to know and it exists  limitation always), there is another more flexible way to do it.

> Using FILE token instead of groovy template

1. using script to access your testing data via [Jenkins API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API), for your case, it is like http://jenkins.server/job/yourjob/lastCompletedBuild/testReport/api/xml and generate your own html file like `email.html` under the workspace
2. In `Default Content` form in the email-ext configuration, using FILE token to send the email directly `${FILE, path="email.html"}`

In step 1 above, you can also use more flexible way for your own template, I use python script and simple string Template.

It works perfect for me.

Comment: Would you care to share the script you described as step 1?

Comment: If you use HTML format, you'll need to use `${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html.template"}` instead of `${FILE}`.

Comment: Can you please be detail on this one. I think I need to do similar thing. I wanted to display complete git commit message from git in the email. But it displays just first line. I think I need to write some script..

Answer (score 5):

To expand on this answer:
Write a Groovy template for Email Ext plugin instead of Jelly template. 
In Editable Email Notification content

- set content type to "HTML" or "Both HTML and Plain Text"
- and include the groovy script like this:

  ${SCRIPT, template="test.groovy"}
- put the groovy script in email-templates home e.g. 
  /var/lib/jenkins/email-templates.  see below test.groovy.

In the example below every test is iterated by getting each of these objects: '''junitResult.getChildren()'''. If one desired to iterate only failed tests then junitResult.getFailedTests() could be used. See the hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult API: http://hudson-ci.org/javadoc/hudson/tasks/junit/PackageResult.html  also see  http://hudson-ci.org/javadoc/hudson/model/Build.html

```
Collection<ClassResult> getChildren()
List<CaseResult>    getFailedTests()
```

Example/template from email-ext-plugin can be seen here:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/groovy-html.template

This example shows summary test result and table for results for each test suite and individual test. test.groovy:

```
<html>
<body>
<%

    import hudson.model.*

    def build = Thread.currentThread().executable
    def buildNumber = build.number
    def buildNumHash = build.getDisplayName()

    def testCount = "0"
    def testPassed = "0"
    def testFailed = "0"
    def testSkipped = "0"
    def buildDuration = "0"
    if(build.testResultAction) {
        def testResult = build.testResultAction
        testCount = String.format("%d",(testResult.totalCount))
        testPassed = String.format("%d",(testResult.result.passCount))
        testFailed = String.format("%d",(testResult.result.failCount))
        testSkipped = String.format("%d",(testResult.result.skipCount))
        testDuration = String.format("%.2f",(testResult.result.duration ))
    }

    def workspace = build.getEnvVars()["WORKSPACE"]
    def buildName = build.getEnvVars()["JOB_NAME"]
    def BUILD_STATUS = build.getEnvVars()["BUILD_STATUS"]
    def BUILD_URL = build.getEnvVars()["BUILD_URL"]

    def testResult = hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult

    def testResult2 = build.getAction(hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction.class)

%>

start test.groovy <br><br>
<b>TEST RESULT:</b> $testCount total, <b>$testPassed pass</b>, <b>$testFailed fail</b>, $testSkipped skip.<br>
Workspace : $workspace<br>
Project Name : $buildName $buildNumHash<br><br>

<!-- GENERAL INFO -->

<TABLE>
  <TR><TD align="right">
    <j:choose>
      <j:when test="${build.result=='SUCCESS'}">
        <IMG SRC="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/32x32/blue.gif" />
      </j:when>
          <j:when test="${build.result=='FAILURE'}">
        <IMG SRC="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/32x32/red.gif" />
      </j:when>
      <j:otherwise>
        <IMG SRC="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/32x32/yellow.gif" />
      </j:otherwise>
    </j:choose>
  </TD><TD valign="center"><B style="font-size: 200%;">BUILD ${build.result}</B></TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>Build URL</TD><TD><A href="${rooturl}${build.url}">${rooturl}${build.url}</A></TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>Project:</TD><TD>${project.name}</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>Date of build:</TD><TD>${it.timestampString}</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>Build duration:</TD><TD>${build.durationString}</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>Test duration:</TD><TD>${testDuration}</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
<BR/>

<!-- JUnit TEMPLATE  hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult   -->

<% def junitResultList = it.JUnitTestResult
try {
 def cucumberTestResultAction = it.getAction("org.jenkinsci.plugins.cucumber.jsontestsupport.CucumberTestResultAction")
 junitResultList.add(cucumberTestResultAction.getResult())
} catch(e) {
        //cucumberTestResultAction not exist in this build
}
// API: http://hudson-ci.org/javadoc/hudson/tasks/junit/PackageResult.html
%>

<!-- JUnit TEMPLATE: all tests PASS FAIL SKIP >
<% 
if (junitResultList.size() > 0) { %>
 <TABLE width="100%">
 <TR><TD class="bg1" colspan="2"><B>${junitResultList.first().displayName}</B></TD></TR>
 <% junitResultList.each{
  junitResult -> %>
     <% junitResult.getChildren().each { packageResult -> %>
        <TR><TD class="bg2" colspan="2"> <B>TEST SUITE: ${packageResult.getName()} Failed: ${packageResult.getFailCount()} test(s), Passed: ${packageResult.getPassCount()} test(s)</B>, Skipped: ${packageResult.getSkipCount()} test(s), Total: ${packageResult.getPassCount()+packageResult.getFailCount()+packageResult.getSkipCount()} test(s)</TD></TR>
        <% packageResult.getChildren().each{ suite -> 
               suite.getChildren().each{ test ->
           def colour = "lightgreen"
           def highlight1=""
           def highlight2=""
           RESULT = test.getStatus() // FAILED or PASSED or SKIPPED
           if (RESULT == hudson.tasks.junit.CaseResult.Status.FAILED || RESULT == hudson.tasks.junit.CaseResult.Status.REGRESSION) {
               colour = "#ffcccc" 
               highlight1="<B>"
               highlight2="</B>"
           }
           if (RESULT == hudson.tasks.junit.CaseResult.Status.SKIPPED) { colour = "#ffffb3" }
         %>
          <TR bgcolor="${colour}"><TD class="test" colspan="2">${highlight1}<li>${RESULT}: ${test.getFullName()} </li>${highlight2}</TD></TR>
        <% } }
      }
 } %>
 </TABLE>
 <BR/>
<%
} %>

end of test.groovy

</body>
</html>
```

e.g. output (text only no colours/formatting)

```
start test.groovy 

TEST RESULT: 18 total, 18 pass, 0 fail, 0 skip. 
Workspace : /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jobname-1/workspace 
Project Name : jobname-1 #20

BUILD SUCCESS 

Build URL   http://jenkinsurl:port/job/jobname-1/20/
Project:    jobname-1 
Date of build:  Mon, 23 Jan 2017 09:29:00 +0000 
Build duration: 10 min 
Test duration:  267.12

Test Results 
TEST SUITE: suitename1 Failed: 0 test(s), Passed: 3 test(s), Skipped: 0 test(s), Total: 3 test(s) 
 * PASSED: suitename1.testclass.testname1
 * PASSED: suitename1.testclass.testname2
 * PASSED: suitename1.testclass.testname3
TEST SUITE: suitename2 Failed: 2 test(s), Passed: 1 test(s), Skipped: 0 test(s), Total: 3 test(s) 
 * PASSED: suitename2.testclass.testname1
 * FAILED: suitename2.testclass.testname2
 * REGRESSION: suitename2.testclass.testname3

end of test.groovy
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution in Jelly basing on default static-analysys.jelly script

```
  <!-- JUnit TEMPLATE -->
  <j:set var="junitResultList" value="${it.JUnitTestResult}" />
  <j:if test="${junitResultList.isEmpty()!=true}">
    <div class="content">
      <a href="${rooturl}${build.url}/testReport">
        <h1>JUnit Tests</h1>
      </a>
      <table class="border">
        <tr>
          <th class="border">Package</th>
          <th class="border">Failed</th>
          <th class="border">Failed (diff)</th>
          <th class="border">Passed</th>
          <th class="border">Passed (diff)</th>
          <th class="border">Skipped</th>
          <th class="border">Skipped (diff)</th>
          <th class="border">Total</th>
          <th class="border">Total (diff)</th>
        </tr>
        <j:forEach var="junitResult" items="${it.JUnitTestResult}">
          <j:forEach var="packageResult" items="${junitResult.getChildren()}">
            <tr>
              <td class="border">
                <tt>${packageResult.getName()}</tt>
              </td>
              <td class="border test_failed">${packageResult.getFailCount()}</td>
              <td class="border test_failed">${packageResult.getFailCount()-packageResult.previousResult.getFailCount()}</td>
              <td class="border test_passed">${packageResult.getPassCount()}</td>
              <td class="border test_passed">${packageResult.getPassCount()-packageResult.previousResult.getPassCount()}</td>
              <td class="border test_skipped">${packageResult.getSkipCount()}</td>
              <td class="border test_skipped">${packageResult.getSkipCount()-packageResult.previousResult.getSkipCount()}</td>
              <td class="border">
                <b>${packageResult.getPassCount()+packageResult.getFailCount()+packageResult.getSkipCount()}
                </b>
              </td>
              <td class="border">
                <b>${packageResult.getPassCount()+packageResult.getFailCount()+packageResult.getSkipCount()-packageResult.previousResult.getPassCount()-packageResult.previousResult.getFailCount()-packageResult.previousResult.getSkipCount()}
                </b>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <j:forEach var="failed_test"
              items="${packageResult.getFailedTests()}">
              <tr>
                <td class="test_failed" colspan="5">
                  <tt>${failed_test.getFullName()}</tt>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </j:forEach>
          </j:forEach>
        </j:forEach>
      </table>
      <br />
    </div>
  </j:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

Made one with **Allure** and **JUnit**

https://gist.github.com/unickq/036224c766a76bdd9eb5de379a187af5
[image]

Comment: @LeeWay here you go https://gist.github.com/unickq/036224c766a76bdd9eb5de379a187af5

Comment: do we need to create the template and put it into a jenkins folder or something? can you please provide full instructions?