# Jenkins: Send XML API content over email

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-email-ext

Jenkins provide XML apis to view build related status:

E.g.: [URL/job/JOBNAME/lastCompletedBuild/testReport/api/xml](https://URL/job/JOBNAME/lastCompletedBuild/testReport/api/xml) will show test results for latest build.

**Is there a way to send the content of this page/api via email?**

If NOT , is there a way to send only summary of Junit status (packages / suites) on email like this (this view is seen on [URL/job/JOBNAME/lastCompletedBuild/testReport/api/xml](https://URL/job/JOBNAME/lastCompletedBuild/testReport/api/xml)):

[image]

(The report generated through Publish Email report is very big and sending it via `${FILE, "index.html"}` results in a very large & ugly email. Also I am not using testNg.)

Answer (score 0):

use email-ext plugin with a groovy template. There is a detailed answer here on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/41803890/1391012